# CAS authentication in angular

Tags: angular, cakephp, jwt, single-sign-on, cas

I am building a dashboard that aims to simplify the usage of multiple business application. The main job of the dashboard is to get data from these applications and send them back to the authenticated user. The dashboard is split between an API written with the framework CakePHP3 where all the logic stands and a client that will just do HTTP requests (not written yet, but planned in angular(2+)).

Flow example : I login to the dashboard, and it tells me I have 5 unread emails in the application A, I have 3 notifications in the application B and I have 5 new documents in the application C. For each of the data received, I have a direct link to access this data inside the targeted business application.

To do so, all the business applications are cassified (CAS client), and the dashboard acts as a proxy CAS (the identity of the authenticated user is transmitted to the cassified applications).

[image: Here is an architecture diagram to explain what we are aiming for]

I've written a CakePHP3 plugin to authenticate to a CAS server. The plugin is straightforward and redirects me to the CAS if I do not have a CAS session (via phpCAS).

On my backend, I have an endpoint that allows me to do proxy request to the business applications, let's call it : `/api/business/:id` (where :id is the id of the application).
Here is my current code using phpCAS that does this proxy request :

```
if (!phpCAS::isAuthenticated()) {
    throw new ForbiddenException('You need to be authenticated to the CAS server.');
}
$this->service = phpCAS::getProxiedService(PHPCAS_PROXIED_SERVICE_HTTP_GET);
$this->service->setUrl($this->url);
try {
    $this->service->send();
    $this->responseCode = $this->service->getResponseStatusCode();
    $this->responseBody = $this->service->getResponseBody();
} 
// willingly removed, not useful in this example
catch () {}
```

Then I'll just manipulate the response code and body to display what I need to the end user.

My main problem is how I should handle the authentication in the angular client. I've tried multiple things but I didn't find a convenient answer.

**Attempt 1** (no authentication method in the client yet)

It needs some preparation :

First

- I request the API through my browser
- I get redirected to the CAS
- I authenticate (session set in my cookies)
- I am redirected to the API

Then I can use the client by simply sending cookies in the HTTP requests (using {withCredentials : true}).

If I were to use this method, I would need to ship the client with some PHP files that would handle the login. On authentication, the user would be redirected to the PHP login page that would take care of the session and redirection to the CAS.

Despite the fact that it could work, I think that basing the requests of the client on cookies he is not really aware of would create more trouble, that it might create some login timeout or other internal problems. This looks like a 'last resort' solution.

**Attempt 2** (using JWT)

I changed my CAS authentication plugin to an existing JWT authentication plugin : https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth

I've added the `cas-server-support-token-webflow` dependency to my CAS server and made sure to use the same signing secret between the CAS and my API.

I then authenticate to the API, it generates a JWT that I store in the localStorage. I'm doing authenticated requests with the header : `Authorization: Bearer <MY_TOKEN>`

When the client requests the endpoint that does proxy requests, I intercept the authorization header.
I've changed the code that do proxy requests (see above) to something like that :

```
$url = CAS_LOGIN_URL . '?service=' . urlencode($this->url) . '&token=' . INTERCEPTED_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN;
// Authenticate to CAS and get a ST
$response = $http->get($url); //  Location header : SERVICE_URL?ticket=ST-...
// Validate the ST
$response = $http->get($response->getHeader('Location')[0]) // Location header : SERVICE_URL
// ST is validated, finally get data
$response = $http->get($response->getHeader('Location')[0])
$this->responseCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$this->responseBody = $response->getBody();
```

This flow is more interesting as it really is stateless. The main problem is that I don't have a session on the browser side. This means that I will send data to the end user (see schema above) and when the user will click on a link, he won't get redirected to the business application but to the CAS where he will need to authenticate once again to create his own session.

To prevent that I could present him a forged url like this : `https://<CAS_LOGIN_URL>?service=<ENCODED_BUSINESS_APP_URL>&token=<TOKEN_IN_LOCALSTORAGE>`. However this is a security flaw since the token would be stored in the user history browser, in the logs from the servers and the user might also leak it by doing a copy/paste from the link.

**Attempt 3** (using CAS REST Protocol)

I didn't tried much this solution but I had similar problems than with the JWT solution so I kinda abandoned it (maybe this was an error ?)

Basically I think the JWT option is the right one but I can't authenticate securely my user and this makes me think that my first attempt is probably more secure but less robust. That's why I'd like to have your opinion on what I did (if I'm not missing something) and what would be my best course of action in my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm creating a cassified app as well..

Comment: Did anyone get solution for this ?

Comment: I guess once a year someone is looking for it ... I'm interested as well, tried mine client-side but got denied by CORS